# Question about と

Tags: particle-と

Can 「私は妹と日本に行きます。」Be written in 「私と妹は日本に行きます。」？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatical, but there's a small difference in meaning.

> - 私は妹と日本に行きます。
>     I (will) go to Japan with my sister.
> - 私と妹は日本に行きます。
>     My sister and I (will) go to Japan.

Depending on the context, one can be more natural than the other.